# How to set up a client/server connection using port forwarding

Tags: sockets, networking, network-programming, port, portforwarding

I created a multi-threaded client/server application that can send messages to each other at real time. Everything works perfectly, but I want to be able to send messages over the Internet. From what I understand, I need to do port forwarding to be able to make my server reachable for the clients. I then set up my port forwarding options by providing a port (9991) and then my Macbook Air's IP Address (192.168.0.1).

I then tried to connect to my server using my public server IP (let's say 197.132.20.222) and it didn't work. I then tried to see if the port forwarding worked by using this website: https://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/ and I realized that the connection was closed. I also tried the command `nc -vz 197.132.20.222 9991` while running my application and the connection is refused.

I'm using a JavaFX application, and for my server side I use a `ServerSocket` with port 9991. For the client side, I use a `Socket` and set the IP Address to my public router IP Address, and I tried to connect with another PC using mobile data to use a different network.

My firewall settings are turn off, so I really don't know what is blocking my application to connect to that port. Could it be my ISP is blocking connections? I just don't understand why my ports are blocked even with no firewalls enabled.

Comment: "*Could it be my ISP is blocking connections?*" - possibly. You would have to contact them and ask. Most ISPs don't want end users running servers on their network without paying extra for that privilege.

Comment: How are you determining your public Internet address? If you are not taking it directly from the the WAN router, then your ISP could be using CGN. That would indicate a residential network, and the Terms of Service for residential networks preclude running services to the public Internet, so your ISP does not care that it does not work, and you need to get a business Internet service or use a hosting service.